# I can't post data from an html table generated by a loop to extract from a database and going into a new page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a loop to populate a html table with available produce. At the end of each row I have a button so the user can select the row. But the data doesn't appear in the next page

I have tried all sorts of advice from this and other sites, but I haven't seen anything using a loop to extract the data, and nothing has worked. (But I have only been learning for 5 weeks...)

```
         <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" 
   cellspacing="0">
            <thead>               
        <tr>
                <th>Load Ref</th>
                <th>Load Time</th>
                <th>Del Time</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Accept</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>Load Ref</th>
                <th>Load Time</th>
                <th>Del Time</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Accept</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>

  <?php

   $sql = "SELECT  loadID, loadTime, tipTime, town_city, delTownCity, 
  loadPrice FROM `loads` WHERE town_city = '$startpoint'";

  $retval = mysqli_query( $con, $sql);

  if(!$retval ) {
  die("Could not get data: ". mysqli_connect_errno());
   }

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) {

   echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td>".
     "<td>$row[1]</td> ".
     "<td>$row[2]</td> ".
     "<td>$row[3]</td> ".
     "<td>$row[4]</td> ".
     "<td>$row[5]</td> ";
     Echo '<td><input type = "button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
     value = "Accept" ></td></tr>';


  }

  echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

  mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
   <script src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>



   $('.table tbody').on('click','.btn',function(){
   var currow = $(this).closest('tr');
   var col1 = currow.find('td:eq(0)').text();
   var col2 = currow.find('td:eq(1)').text();
   var col3 = currow.find('td:eq(2)').text();
   var col4 = currow.find('td:eq(3)').text();
   var col5 = currow.find('td:eq(4)').text();
   var col6 = currow.find('td:eq(5)').text();
   var result = col1+'\n'+col2+'\n'+col3+'\n'+col4+'\n'+col5+'\n'+col6;


   console.log(result);
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "accept.php",
         data: 'result'
           });
              alert(result);
              window.location.href ="accept.php";
          })

         </script>
```

I just need to see the data in the new page "accept.php". it shows in the console on the first page, but then everything is empty in the second page.

Comment: `window.location.href ="accept.php";` is just making a page transition to the accept.php page.  You're not passing it any data.  Unless you store the data as part of the ajax call to accept before redirecting to it, or pass the data to it in the url, it's not going to know what you previously passed it as there is no state provided.

Comment: Also `data: 'result'` is giving the ajax request a **literal string** of "result" to the ajax call.

Comment: I do get a console entry as follows:- VM36 jquery.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://www.klcg.co.uk/accept.php". just as I click ok on the alert and then get redirected to accept.php

Comment: That doesn't address either of my previous two points.  Just because the endpoint returned 200 doesn't mean it's doing what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: I hope you noticed the most important info - I have been at this for 5 weeks!! How do I store the data as part of the ajax call?

Comment: #1) Fix your `data: 'result'` so it's actually giving the data to the ajax (remove the single quotes around the variable).  #2) Determine how `accept.php` is expected to persist the data given to it, if it is supposed to at all.  Which is entirely up to you.  If you are not going to persist the data on the backend, then the redirect will have to give the data to it on the redirect as a normal GET query string.

Comment: Thanks Taplar - I have done #1. #2) I want to use the data to then remove that row from the table and copy it into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to thank Taplar for help - it made me think about it enough to solve it.

```
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "accept.php",
     data: result
       });
          alert(result);
          window.location.href ="accept.php&loadID="col1;
      })

     </script>
```

This puts the data into the URL, and $answer =  $_GET ['loadID']; can access it on the next page. I have no idea why nobody pointed this out, maybe it's easy to forget what it's like to be learning from scratch. If this is not a recommended method please comment - any learning is appreciated! (My pages only have the option to select and no user input, and each page must have authorised user. So I am assuming there is no danger of injection...)